# In XML, how/why can you use a namespace before it is defined?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

I have seen examples like the one below where `xs` is used before it is declared [if that is the correct word] using `xmlns`. How is this possible?

Here is the kind of code I am referring to. You can find it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</xs:schema>
```

Why is it that `xs:schema` is allowed when `xlmns:xs` comes later? How is this resolved?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this can be quite hard to disentangle in XQuery, which uses an XML-like syntax but allows more complexity in attributes: so in XQuery you can write, for example, `<xs:schema version="{$v[@x="3"]}" xmlns:xs="..."/>`: scanning forward in XQuery to find the namespace declaration becomes quite tricky because of the nested quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `xs:` namespace prefix in `xs:schema` appears ***lexically before*** its declaration, the ***scope*** of the declaration actually includes the element on which the declaration appears (and all its descendants), so

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</xs:schema>
```

is perfectly proper (and quite common).

Comment: And the answer to "how it is resolved?" is that the syntactic analysis to identify elements and attribute can be completed before the semantics analysis to work out which prefixes refer to which namespaces.

Comment: @MichaelKay, would you like to add an answer so that I can upvote it as well?